# React redux api polling every x seconds

Tags: reactjs, redux, polling

I've got this working but i'm after a more 'best practice way'.

its using the https://icanhazdadjoke api to display a random joke that gets updated every x seconds. is there a better way of doing this?

eventually i want to add stop, start, reset functionality and feel this way might not be the best.

Any middleware i can use?

Redux actions

```
// action types
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_JOKE = 'FETCH_JOKE';
export const FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE = 'FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE';


function fetchJoke() {
  return {
    type: FETCH_JOKE
  };
}

function fetchJokeSuccess(data) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS,
    data
  };
}

function fetchJokeFail(error) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE,
    error
  };
}

export function fetchJokeCall(){
  return function(dispatch){
    dispatch(fetchJoke());
    return axios.get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com', { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }})
    .then(function(result){
      dispatch(fetchJokeSuccess(result.data))
    })
    .catch(error => dispatch(fetchJokeFail(error)));
  }
}
```

Redux reducer

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {FETCH_JOKE, FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS, FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE} from '../actions';

const defaultStateList = {
  isFetching: false,
  items:[],
  error:{}
};

const joke = (state = defaultStateList, action) => {
  switch (action.type){
  case FETCH_JOKE:
    return {...state, isFetching:true};
  case FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS:
    return {...state, isFetching:false, items:action.data};
  case FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE:
    return {...state, isFetching:false, error:action.data};
  default:
    return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  joke
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Joke component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { fetchJokeCall } from '../actions';


class Joke extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(()=>  this.props.fetchJokeCall(), 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
    this.timer = null;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.joke.joke}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Joke.propTypes = {
  fetchJokeCall: PropTypes.func,
  joke: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    joke: state.joke.items,
    isfetching: state.joke.isFetching
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchJokeCall })(Joke);
```

Comment: You can try out Thunk middleware, you dispatch your fetch results using your actions to apply to your state. It's a very small library and used quite a lot.

Comment: He is using redux thunk already it looks like. I would suggest you check our Nir Kaufmans book on writing your own middleware. All of these side affects are great in middleware.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Redux-Sagas is better and we are using it in our applications as well, this is how you can poll using Redux-Sagas

***Just to give you an idea this is how you can do it, You also need to understand how Redux-Sagas work***

**Action**

```
export const FETCH_JOKE = 'FETCH_JOKE';
export const FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE = 'FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE';
export const START_POLLING = 'START_POLLING';
export const STOP_POLLING = 'STOP_POLLING';

function startPolling() {
      return {
        type: START_POLLING
      };
    }

function stopPolling() {
      return {
        type: STOP_POLLING
      };
    }

function fetchJoke() {
  return {
    type: FETCH_JOKE
  };
}

function fetchJokeSuccess(data) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS,
    data
  };
}

function fetchJokeFail(error) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE,
    error
  };
}
```

**Reducer**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {FETCH_JOKE, FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS, FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE, START_POLLING, STOP_POLLING } from '../actions';

const defaultStateList = {
  isFetching: false,
  items:[],
  error:{},
  isPolling: false,
};

const joke = (state = defaultStateList, action) => {
  switch (action.type){
  case FETCH_JOKE:
    return {...state, isFetching:true};
  case FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS:
    return {...state, isFetching:false, items:action.data};
  case FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE:
    return {...state, isFetching:false, error:action.data};
  case START_POLLING:
    return {...state, isPolling: true};
  case STOP_POLLING:
    return {...state, isPolling: false};
  default:
    return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  joke
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**Sagas**

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, takeLatest, take, race } from 'redux-saga/effects'

import {FETCH_JOKE, FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS, FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE, START_POLLING, STOP_POLLING } from '../actions';

import axios from 'axios';



function delay(duration) {
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(true), duration)
  })
  return promise
}

function* fetchJokes(action) {
  while (true) {
    try {
      const { data } = yield call(() => axios({ url: ENDPOINT }))
      yield put({ type: FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS, data: data })
      yield call(delay, 5000)
    } catch (e) {
      yield put({ type: FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE, message: e.message })
    }
  }
}

function* watchPollJokesSaga() {
  while (true) {
    const data = yield take(START_POLLING)
    yield race([call(fetchJokes, data), take(STOP_POLLING)])
  }
}

export default function* root() {
  yield [watchPollJokesSaga()]
}
```

You can also use Redux-Observable, if you want to get more into this read this [article](https://bigbitecreative.com/polling-with-redux/)

Comment: Can you show me a fiddle of this working? maybe with random joke api (https://icanhazdadjoke.com/api)

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @Adam Did you implemented this, i think this is the answer since you wanted to implement the polling using redux?

Comment: 'payloadIfAny' is not defined , 'dataIfAny' is not defined. also in the watch you are defining data but never using it.

Comment: this is an idea of how you can poll using redux sagas, i know that this chunk of code may not work right now. Read this it will help you alot 
https://bigbitecreative.com/polling-with-redux/

Comment: The watchPollJokesSaga is also never being called. i don/t think this is the answer as its unclear what it does

Comment: Also the delay doesn/t work. unless you change the order which then leaves a massive delay on first load     
yield call(delay, 5000) 
yield put({ type: FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS, data: data })

Comment: I think you need to do a bit of research on redux-saga because it can be a bit tricky to understand. BTW you need to createSagaMiddleware() and createStore() and then run the saga middleware.

Comment: It is tricky, which is why i asked for a working fiddle as an answer. what you provided doesn't work and is only making a tricky subject even more so. Can you provide a working fiddle?

Comment: Updated the answer hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, i did something very similar today. i can confirm your example works which will be great at helping others. But now i have it working im thinking websockets might be a better more modern solution. thoughts?

Comment: Yes you are right I have used webSockets as well and you don't need polling because you can implement listeners and callback functions but I think using webSockets only for fetching an API data is not what i would like to do. I would use webSockets for realtime stuff like chat or videoCall.

Comment: Yes agree but i'm working on an app where a user action on a record will put it in a process where the status of that record will change from e.g incomplete, in progress, complete. just thinking that might be better suited for websockets as i'll have controls over the backend in node to send the updated records. do you agree?

Comment: Agree. if you want to get rid of useless network consumption and be realtime as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on pretty much the same problem, except that I wasn't concerned about starting and stopping the poll.  For some reason the while loop kept freezing my app so I dispensed of it and instead set up my saga like this.

```
import { all, takeLatest, call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import axios from 'axios';

import { API_CALL_REQUEST, API_CALL_SUCCESS, API_CALL_FAILURE, API_CALL_FETCHED } from 
'../actions/giphy';

function apiFetch() {
  let randomWord = require('random-words');
  let API_ENDPOINT = `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search? 
                   api_key=MYKEY&q=${randomWord()}&limit=12`;
  return axios({
    method: "get",
    url: API_ENDPOINT
 });
}

export function* fetchImages() {
  try {
   const res = yield call(apiFetch)
   const images = yield res.data
   yield put({type: API_CALL_SUCCESS, images})

} catch (e) {
  yield put({type: API_CALL_FAILURE, e})
  console.log('Error fetching giphy data')
 }
}

export default function* giphySaga() {
  yield all([
    takeLatest(API_CALL_REQUEST, fetchImages),
 ]);
}
```

Then inside my component I added this.

```
 componentDidMount() {
   this.interval = setInterval(() => {
   this.props.dispatch({type: 'API_CALL_REQUEST'});
   }, 5000);
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.interval)
}
```

It's working, but would like some feedback on how this could be possibly improved.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a poor man's way. I don't think it's the best way but it doesn't require any extra library.

Actions

```
// action types
import axios from 'axios';

export const START_POLLING_JOKE = 'START_POLLING_JOKE';
export const STOP_POLLING_JOKE = 'STOP_POLLING_JOKE';
export const FETCH_JOKE = 'FETCH_JOKE';
export const FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE = 'FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE';

const defaultPollingInterval = 60000

function startPollingJoke(interval = defaultPollingInterval) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    const fetch = () => dispatch(fetchJoke())
    dispatch({
      type: START_POLLING_JOKE,
      interval,
      fetch,
    })
  }
}

function stopPollingJoke() {
  return {
    type: STOP_POLLING_JOKE
  }
}

function fetchJoke() {
  return {
    type: FETCH_JOKE
  };
}

function fetchJokeSuccess(data) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS,
    data
  };
}

function fetchJokeFail(error) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE,
    error
  };
}

export function pollJokeCall(interval = defaultPollingInterval) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(fetchJoke())
    dispatch(startPollingJoke(interval))
  }
}

export function fetchJokeCall() {
  return function(dispatch){
    dispatch(fetchJoke());
    return axios.get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com', { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }})
    .then(function(result){
      dispatch(fetchJokeSuccess(result.data))
    })
    .catch(error => dispatch(fetchJokeFail(error)));
  }
}
```

Reducers

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {
  START_POLLING_JOKE,
  STOP_POLLING_JOKE,
  FETCH_JOKE, 
  FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS, 
  FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE,
} from '../actions';

const defaultStateList = {
  isFetching: false,
  items:[],
  error:{},
  pollingId: null,
  polling: false,
};

const joke = (state = defaultStateList, action) => {
  switch (action.type){
  case START_POLLING_JOKE: 
    clearInterval(state.pollingId)
    return {
      ...state,
      polling: true,
      pollingId: setInterval(action.fetch, action.interval),
    }
  }
  case STOP_POLLING_JOKE: 
    clearInterval(state.pollingId)
    return {...state, polling: false, pollingId: null}
  case FETCH_JOKE:
    return {...state, isFetching:true};
  case FETCH_JOKE_SUCCESS:
    return {...state, isFetching:false, items:action.data};
  case FETCH_JOKE_FAILURE:
    return {...state, isFetching:false, error:action.data};
  default:
    return state;
  }
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  joke
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Component (might have a bug because I'm not used to class components)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { pollJokeCall, stopPollingJoke } from '../actions';


class Joke extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.pollJokeCall()
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.stopPollingJoke()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.joke.joke}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Joke.propTypes = {
  pollJokeCall: PropTypes.func,
  stopPollingJoke: PropTypes.func,
  joke: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    joke: state.joke.items,
    isfetching: state.joke.isFetching
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { pollJokeCall, stopPollingJoke })(Joke);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a small (5kb gzipped) helper to create polling based on redux-thunk store. The idea is to have a logic to prevent registering the same polling twice, have callbacks between iterations and more.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-polling-thunk

Answer (score 0):

[`redux-saga`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) is great and I've been using this with redux. It provides a great api to do things like delay, polling, throttling, race conditions, task cancellations. So using redux-saga, you can add a watcher whcih will keep on pooling

```js
function* pollSagaWorker(action) {
  while (true) {
    try {
      const { data } = yield call(() => axios({ url: ENDPOINT }));
      yield put(getDataSuccessAction(data));
      yield call(delay, 4000);
    } catch (err) {
      yield put(getDataFailureAction(err));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that `while (true)` loop necessary? Seems like something I want to avoid.

Comment: Thanks. I've built on my example to use a different api that populates a table. With redux-saga will this prevent the whole table refreshing each time? also what about using websockets? is this way good for performance?