# Call an api in each 3 seconds in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to call a api continuously at 3 seconds interval.I am trying with `async` and `setInterval` but not working at all.
Let's look at my code below

`component.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchMarketCap } from '../Actions/Marketcap';

class Header extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        setInterval(this.props.fetchMarketCap(), 3000);
    }
    render(){
        const marketcap = this.props.marketcap.map(coin => (
                <div key={coin.CoinInfo.Id}>
                    <h5>{coin.CoinInfo.Name}</h5>
                    <h5>{coin.RAW.USD.CHANGE24HOUR}</h5>
                </div>
        ));
        return (
            <div>
                {marketcap}
            </div>

        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    marketcap: state.marketcap.coins
});
export default connect ( mapStateToProps, { fetchMarketCap } )(Header);
```

and expected action file `Marketcap.js`

```
import { FETCH_MARKET_CAP, FETCH_MARKET_CAP_SUCCEED, FETCH_MARKET_CAP_FAILED } from './Types';

export const fetchMarketCap = async () => async dispatch => {
    const res = await fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/mktcapfull?limit=10&tsym=USD&api_key=46e898b0b5d0319ab6fb94aae5ed2f1a388ff650bffefa1f32f5af1479766b4f');
    const response = await res.json()
        .then( marketcaps => 
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_MARKET_CAP_SUCCEED,
                payload: marketcaps.Data
            })
        )
}
```

but in console `SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:52) in Marketcap.js.Unexpected token (10:52)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.` in the console.How can i solve it?

Comment: Looks like you have an SyntaxError - maybe just use something like prettier to format on save and stop dealing with such errors. (https://github.com/prettier/prettier)

Comment: @davidbucka Unexpected token (10:52)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious thing is the use of the `async` keyword... Get rid of the first `async` like so:

```
export const fetchMarketCap = () => async dispatch => {
    const res = await fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/mktcapfull?limit=10&tsym=USD&api_key=46e898b0b5d0319ab6fb94aae5ed2f1a388ff650bffefa1f32f5af1479766b4f');
    const response = await res.json()
        .then( marketcaps => 
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_MARKET_CAP_SUCCEED,
                payload: marketcaps.Data
            })
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this in the past in by using Redux-Sagas middleware. It lets you poll every x seconds, and allows you to start and stop the polling using actions.

See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52422831/6640093